# Android Google Maps: Combine scrollBy with zoomBy for simultaneous pan & zoom

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'd like to both zoom and scroll a `GoogleMap` object at the same time. Unfortunately, it seems like if I just make two `moveCamera` calls (one after another), only the second call appears to take effect.

An alternative approach would be to pass a `CameraPosition`, but unfortunately it looks like the `CameraPosition` constructor does not take an argument that deals with an amount to scroll (which is invariant to the zoom level), but only an argument as to what lat/lon to go to.

Is there some clever way to combine/concatenate `CameraUpdate` objects so I can just issue one `moveCamera` command that does both a pan and a zoom?

I assume something like this is possible because you can do it when you're touching the map. You put down two fingers, and you can zoom in/out by spreading your fingers and pan by moving them both simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your best option will be to modify the `CameraPosition` object returned when you call `GoogleMap.getCameraPosition()`. However, you won't be able to just increment that latitude and longitude of the `CameraPosition` object by the number of pixels you scrolled. You'll have to get the `CameraPosition`'s LatLng coordinates, convert that to a `Point` object using the `Projection` class, modify the `Point`, and then convert it back into a `LatLng` object.

**For example**:

```
GoogleMap map; // This is your GoogleMap object
int dx; // X distance scrolled
int dy; // Y distance scrolled
float dz; // Change in zoom level
float originalZoom;

CameraPosition position = map.getCameraPosition();
Project projection = map.getProjection();

LatLng mapTarget = position.target;
originalZoom = position.zoom;

Point mapPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(mapTarget);
mapPoint.x += dx;
mapPoint.y += dy;
mapTarget = projection.fromScreenLocation(mapPoint);

CameraPosition newPosition = new CameraPosition(position)
                                  .target(mapTarget)
                                  .zoom(originalZoom+dz)
                                  .build();

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(newPosition));
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this. I'll give it a shot and get back to you. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: So... this is really, really close. Maybe about the best we can do? But the current problem is that the zoom always zooms with a focus based on the centre of the map. In my application, there's a little cursor that moves around that you can control in X, Y, and Z. If I turn off the zooming, this solution works really well for scrolling. But when zooming is turned on, the effect is not correct when you try to zoom at the edge of the map because it's zooming toward the centre instead of the cursor position. Again, this may be the best that's possible, so I may go with it!

Comment: I think I'd basically need the `zoom` function with a focus point to make this work the way I'd like... but again, I think this may be the closest possible solution?

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in zoom and scroll features? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.  Are you handling touch events for the map somewhere else?

Comment: Because I'm trying to zoom and scroll at the same time, so I can't use the scroll and zoom features that the map exposes because they "fight" each other. The interaction method is not touch-based -- I'm using an external control to move the map, so the fact that the touch control works properly doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Aha, if you're trying to zoom into a specific point on your screen, it looks like the google maps api provides a zoomBy(amount, focuspoint) function: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory

Comment: Right, but then I can't use the `scrollBy` as well, because they 'fight' each other. Only one seems to take effect, but not both.

Comment: Only the second call actually takes effect, so if I call `scrollBy` then `zoomBy`, the map will only zoom.

Comment: In what situation would you need to call both functions? If you are zooming into a specific point on the map that you can see, use `zoomBy`, otherwise if you need to move the map a bunch use `scrollBy` and then `moveCamera` first to get the map into a correct position and then call `zoomBy`

Comment: Imagine it's just like you're using two fingers on the map: you can slide the two fingers to pan while also zooming by spreading them apart. You're not "panning then zooming" (or the converse), you're performing them both simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

There is this method `newLatLngZoom (LatLng latLng, float zoom)`, which will zoom to the point located at latLng. For your case of zooming to a point P  that is off the center, it is able to do it with some math involves.

To reverse thinking about the problem, we know the screen coordinate of the map center C after the zoom so that we know the LatLng of C. This LatLng needs to be passed in to the newLatLngZoom method so that it will center to the point and P is the same as before (which is as we defined the problem, zoom to P). So we need to find the screen coordinate of C before the zoom.

Let's assume the zoom value before zoom is z1, and after zoom is `z1 + dz`. Google map API states that at zoom level N, the width of the world is approximately 256*2^N dp. So the width of the world before is `256*2^z1`, and after is `256*2^(z1 + dz)`.

We also know that the ratio of the distance of P to C to the whole world doesn't change before and after the zoom. The coordinate of C after the zoom is just center of your map view, which is known. Let's assume coordinate of C before the zoom as (Cx, Cy), then we can have our equation as `(Px - Cx) / 256*2^z1 = (Px - C'x) / 256*2^(z1 + dz)`, and `(Py - Cy) / 256*2^z1 = (Py - C'y) / 256*2^(z1 + dz)`. I ignore the aspect ratio to transfer width to height, because it will be cancelled out as you solve the equation.

Solve the equation for Cx and Cy, and use that value as your parameters in newLatLngZoom. If you want to add panning and you know the dx dy value that needs to be panned, then just calculate the dx' dy' in the map after the zoom and add that to C.

Comment: Just curious, how is this different from creating a CameraPosition with a target of `latLng` and a zoom of `zoom`, and then creating a CameraUpdate to this position/zoom with the CameraUpdateFactory? Is `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom()` just a shortcut to creating a new CameraPosition and then a CameraUpdate to that position, or is there more to it?

Comment: The CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom() is the same as creating a CameraPosition and then doing a CameraUpdate.